# Como saber quantos pontos e votos tenho em uma tag?

Tags: suporte, tags

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de saber quantos pontos tenho em uma tag, estou interessado nas **medalhas de tag** de bronze, prata e ouro:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold

Mas não sei quantos pontos me faltam pra conseguir uma.

Comment: **Ministério da saúde adverte:** Responder as suas próprias perguntas pode ser interpretado mal =)

Comment: Vim correndo na pergunta pra postar uma query no data.se, mas já tem uma reposta mais simples e "Amigável" kkkk

Comment: @DiegoF posta também, vai que alguém quer mudar um pouco a query pra verificar N possibilidades =)

Comment: Aqui, só colocar o userId : http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/785/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siga estes passos:

Vá até o seu perfil > Aba <kbd>Participação</kbd> > Aba <kbd>Tags</kbd>, vai aparecer todas a tags que você usou em perguntas que você fez ou respondeu.

Passe o mouse sob o numero a "esquerda", note que irá aparecer uma mensagem semelhante a isto:

- Se tiver apenas respostas em uma tag:

  > Deu X respostas não-comunitárias com um total de Y pontos.
- Se tiver apenas perguntas em uma tag:

  > Fez X perguntas não wiki com uma pontuação total de Y.
- Se tiver perguntas e respostas em uma tag:

  > Fez X perguntas não wiki com uma pontuação total de 30. Deu X respostas não-comunitárias com um total de Y pontos.

Veja um exemplo, eu quero ver quantos pontos tenho na tag [.net](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net), então eu passo o cursor do mouse (rato) em cima do numero 8:

> [image: tag .net]

Tenho atualmente 2 respostas com um total de 8 pontos, a tag bronze diz:

> Obter mais de 100 pontos, em 20 ou mais respostas na tag .net que não sejam wiki.

Então preciso responder mais 18 vezes no minimo e ganhar mais 92 pontos nesta tag.